# How can I read numbers from a .txt file and put them into a 2-D array?

Tags: java

This is for a school project. I need to read numbers from a .txt file and put them into an array. After they're in an array, I need to pass it into a different class to do the math and compare the numbers. The only problem is, I can't get the code to read the .txt file or make it into an array.

I need to use

```
    if (sq.isMagicSquare())
```

to pass the array to class Square, but it gives the error:

```
required: int[][]

found: no arguments

reason: actual and formal lists differ in length

public class MagicSquareTester
{
public static void main() throws IOException
{
    Square sq = null;       

    System.out.println("Enter the name of your data file (magicData.txt):");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();              // input data file name from keyboard

    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File (fileName));
    int sqSize = inFile.nextInt();                      // read the size 

    while (sqSize != -1)
    {
        sq = new Square(sqSize, inFile);
        if (sq.isMagicSquare())  //will return true or false
            System.out.println("\tWe have a Magic Square!");
        else
            System.out.println("\tThis is NOT a Magic Square.");

        System.out.println(sq);
        System.out.println();
        sqSize = inFile.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Of the " + sq.getTotalTested() + " squares tested " + sq.getMagicCount() + " were magic square(s)" );
}
}

public class Square
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //has been imported correctly, btw
    int tested = 0, areMagic = 0, sqSize;
    boolean magic;
    int[][] Square;

    public Square(int sqSize, Scanner inFile)
    {
        Square = new int [sqSize] [sqSize];
    }

    public void readSquare(Scanner inFile)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row < sqSize; row++)
            for(int col = 0; col < sqSize; col++)
            {
                Square[row][col] = inFile.nextInt();
                tested++;
            }
    }

    public boolean isMagicSquare(int[][] array)
    {
        Sums testMagic = new Sums();
        int rows = testMagic.sumRows(array);
        int cols = testMagic.sumCol(array);
        int diagonals = testMagic.sumDiagonal(array);

        if((rows == cols) && (cols == diagonals) && (diagonals == rows))
        {
            magic = true;
            areMagic++;
        }
        else 
            magic = false;
        return magic;
    }

    public int getMagicCount()
    {
        return areMagic;
    }

    public int getTotalTested()
    {
        return tested;     
    }
}



public class Sums
{
    int sum = 0, lastSum = 0, counter1, counter2, counter3;
    boolean magic = true;

    public int sumRows(int [][] array)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) 
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (int col = 0; col < array.length; col++) 
            {
                sum += array[row][col];
                System.out.print(sum + " ");
                if (lastSum == sum) 
                {
                    lastSum = sum;
                    counter1++;
                }
                else if (lastSum != sum) 
                    {
                        magic = false;
                        System.out.println("This is not a magic square");
                        row = array.length;
                        col = array.length;
                    }
            }
        }
        return counter1;
    }

    public int sumCol(int [][] array)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < array.length; col++) 
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) 
            {
                sum += array[row][col];
                System.out.print(sum + " ");
                if (lastSum == sum) 
                {
                    lastSum = sum;
                    counter2++;
                }
                else if (lastSum != sum) 
                    {
                        magic = false;
                        System.out.println("This is not a magic square");
                        row = array.length;
                        col = array.length;
                    }
            }  
        }
        return counter2;
    }

    public int sumDiagonal(int [][] array)
    {
        int diagonal1 = 0, diagonal2 = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < array.length; col++) 
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) 
            {
                if(row == col)
                {
                    sum += array[row][col];
                    System.out.print(sum + " ");
                    diagonal1 = sum;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < array.length; col--) 
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) 
            {
                if((row + col) == array.length - 1)
                {
                    sum += array[row][col];
                    System.out.print(sum + " ");
                    diagonal2 = sum;
                }
            }
        }

        if(diagonal1 == diagonal2)
        {
            magic = true;
            counter2 = counter3;
        }
        else
            counter3 = 0;

        return counter3;
    }
}
```

Also, apologies if my code looks weirdly formatted. I've never posted here before and I'm doing my best.

Comment: This doesn't compile, doesn't it.

Comment: @user871611:  It looks like it'd compile to me if a definition of `Sums` were included...not sure what the hang-up is.

Comment: See [ask]. You should supply a [mcve] and tell us exactly what your problem is and what you need to do. Show what research you have done, along with any errors or messages. My advice is use an IDE and _pay attention to the help it gives you_. IDEs also have excellent debuggers that new coders should be _required_ to learn.

Comment: @user871611: It only doesn't compile because of the error described in my question. No need to be rude.

Comment: Sorry if it sounded rude, never was the intention. But the more precise you are, the more helpful answers you get. People are very helpful on this platform, but like to see initial effort of your own.

Comment: @user871611: Sorry if it didn't seem like I did all I could. I was researching this for the last week and testing different things. I just turned here as a second to last resort. I'll probably just ask my teacher on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use java.io.file and separate the squaring and parsing operations from the file reading operations.
Possibly like follows:

```
public class MathSquareTester {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Integer> squaredNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file_name);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(in));

        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            //Assuming each line represents a separate integer

            squaredNums.add((int)Math.pow(Integer.parseInt(line)), 2);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        int[] numsArray = new int[squaredNums.size];
        squaredNums.toArray(numsArray);
        //All of your numbers are now stored in numsArray
    }
}
```